# How to find all documents having an identical values in two fields with MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
Given that new Documents and querys:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55803fd1cc0c9aa090e608be"),
    "song_name" : "Mickey is good",
    "time" : "3.56",
    "artist" : "Mickey"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55803fd1cc0c9aa090e608bf"),
    "song_name" : "Love is nothing",
    "time" : "5.56",
    "artist" : "Jimmy"
}
```

I need to find which songs have a title identical to the artist name. 
i have tried: 
db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.artist == /this.song_name/" } );

but did not work out. please help`

Comment: what have u done so far, please share...

Comment: i have modified my query with what i did so far..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it well, you need to find all [songs whose title *contains* the name of the artist](http://www.songfacts.com/category-song_titles_with_the_artist%27s_name.php). You don't need a regular expression for that<sup>1</sup>. As simple test using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) would suffice. Given your sample data:

```
> db.test.find({$where:
      "this.song_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.artist.toLowerCase()) > -1"
})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("557ccec684ee2ba0375f4fcf"),
  "song_name" : "Mickey is good",
  "time" : "3.56",
  "artist" : "Mickey" }
```

---

If you really need to find the songs whose title *is equal* to the artist name (you don't have such a document in your sample data), you would simply write:

```
> db.test.find({$where:
      "this.song_name.toLowerCase() == this.artist.toLowerCase()"
})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("557cd12284ee2ba0375f4fd1"),
  "song_name" : "The Monkeys",
  "artist" : "The Monkeys" }
```

Please note in either cases, I've normalized the strings using `toLowerCase()`. Depending your use case, you might need something much more sophisticated than that. For example, if you need to match [*"You and Me"* by *"You+Me"*](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=34706).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Using a regular expression here might even be harmful if the artist name contains meta-characters or quantifiers. For example, given the artist name *"You+Me"*, the `+` here would be interpreted as *1 or more occurrence of the preceding character*. So, matching *"YouMe"*, "YouuuuuMe" *but not* the raw string *"You+Me"*.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside the delimiters is considered a "String" and not a variable anymore. Also on the "Right Hand Side this comparison is not valid. So instead do

```js
db.test.find({ "$where": " return new RegExp(this.artist,i).test(this.song_name);" })
```

So [**`RegExp()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) compiles a pattern from the variable whereas `//` considers all contained to the a string literal. The [**`.test()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method is how you do the comparison to content with a regular expression for a "Boolean" result.

True that [**`.indeOf()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) "should" be faster than a regular expression for basic strings, but if you need the case insensitive comparison then `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` introduce another cost of their own, so the negilgable difference is lost.

Also I think it just looks neater.